# Unzip file without physical save in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, zip

unzip file without physical save when we post local direction of zip file

I want to Unzip file without physical save in spring boot when i post the file in local directory

Comment: share your code.

Comment: @kerbermeister zip code is every where i want solution that do not need physical storagee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `java.util.zip.ZipInpuStream` to unzip and read contents of compressed file without saving it to file but having `byte[]` instead:

```java
public class UnzipFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileZip = "src/main/resources/unzipTest/compressed.zip";

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileZip);
        unzipAndUse(in);// here you can pass any InputStream, e.g. ByteArrayInputStream wrapping POST request body
    }

    private static void unzipAndUse(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(in)) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
            while (zipEntry != null) {
                byte[] bytes = zis.readAllBytes(); // your data
                zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
            }

            zis.closeEntry();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in java 1.8 we do not have readAllBytes

Comment: @Tara in Java 8 you can use Apache's IOUtils

Comment: thanks a lot.just How can i use Apache's IOUtils method and classes instead of this methods

Comment: Use IOUtils.readFully() or Guava's ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);

Comment: You are welcome! Please vote my answer up if it's helpful

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."  
@Sergey Tsypanov i can not vote but i mark as true answer thanks and sorry